# Flowtype annotation for callback

Tags: javascript, flowtype

When i am trying to make this annotation Flowtype does not check types

```
declare function MyType(x: number): void;
type PropsT = {
  onClick?: MyType;
};

props.onClick && props.onClick(); // no check
```

but this works.

```
type PropsT = {
  onClick?: (x: number) => void;
};
props.onClick && props.onClick(); // ERROR
```

Question - why?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

When you write `declare function MyType` you don't declare a type name `MyType`, but you declare that a function `MyType` with specified signature exists. So, `MyType` is a value, not a type. Usually, when you use value as a type, Flow will print something like this:

```
Ineligible value used in/as type annotation (did you forget 'typeof'?)
```

The only exception is functions. Flow allows use functions as type to support old style classes:

```
function Foo() {}
const foo: Foo = new Foo();
```

Unfortunately, behaviour of such classes is mostly unsafe, Flow infers type of some properties, but treats everything else as `any`.

Long story short, you need to add `typeof`:

```
type PropsT = {
  onClick?: typeof MyType;
};
```